# Getting words not found when querying indexing service

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexing-service

is there a way, when querying an indexing service catalog, to have a list of words that compose the search input but have not be found?
Example: i'm querying my catalog for 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', but none of the documents in my catalog contains the words 'quick' nor 'lazy'.
I'd like to have 'quick' and 'lazy' returned from indexing service as "not found words".

Please note: i've already rejected the solution of splitting the input in its composing words and performing a search for each word in the list, because i think it's inefficient.

Please note II: Indexing service is a "must use", any other indexing software cannot be used.

Thanks

Claudio

Comment: Why don't you use Windows Search instead of  Indexing service? Did you try splitting the input in its composing words? Maybe it is not so slow as you think?

Comment: Hi Taras.
I'm using Indexing Service because the customer's website is a legacy website 10+ years old, on a Windows 2003 Server. Though Windows Search has been wrapped in the web application, there is no will from the client to spend money in re-testing all the working stuff that depends on the search engine (and it's a lot!).

Word splitting could work for small sentences (2-3 words) on a small website, but this one has thousand of users making complex legal searches, I just don't think it's a good idea to multiply the requests to the indexing service by 10-15 times only for this goal.